# BFS shortest path program

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

The task was to find the shortest path between P and K in a maze. You can move horizontally and vertically, where `#` is a wall and `.` is free space. I've had a lot of trouble passing on the `int k`, which is the path length. I had to make a pair which contains a pair of `x` and `y` coordinates and `int k`.

Could I have done this any better without too much change in the code, especially with the pairs and the `while` loop? And how good is my code overall?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int dfs(string g[30][30], pair<int, int> p)
{
    vector <pair<pair<int, int>, int> > v;
    int visited[30][30] = {0};
    int x, y, k = 0;
    pair <pair<int, int>, int> mj;
    pair <pair<int, int>, int> z;
    pair <int, int> l;
    z = make_pair(make_pair(p.first, p.second), 0);
    v.push_back(z);
    while(v.size() != 0)
    {
        mj = v.front();
        l = mj.first;
        x = l.first;
        y = l.second;
        k = mj.second;
        v.erase(v.begin());
        if(g[x][y] == "K")
            return k;
        if((g[x+1][y] == "." or g[x+1][y] == "K") and not(visited[x+1][y]))
        {
            v.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(x+1, y), k+1));
            visited[x+1][y] = 1;
        }
        if((g[x][y+1] == "." or g[x][y+1] == "K") and not(visited[x][y+1]))
        {
            v.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(x, y+1), k+1));
            visited[x][y+1] = 1;
        }
        if((g[x-1][y] == "." or g[x-1][y] == "K") and not(visited[x-1][y]))
        {
            v.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(x-1, y), k+1));
            visited[x-1][y] = 1;
        }
        if((g[x][y-1] == "." or g[x][y-1] == "K") and not(visited[x][y-1]))
        {
            v.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(x, y-1), k+1));
            visited[x][y-1] = 1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    pair <int, int> p;
    string s, g[30][30];
    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> s;
        for(int j = 0; j < s.size(); j++)
        {
            g[i][j] = s.substr(j, 1);
            if(g[i][j] == "P")
                p = make_pair(i, j);
        }
    }
    cout << dfs(g, p);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

> ```
> 6
> 10
> ##########
> #.P#.....#
> ##.#.K#..#
> #..####..#
> #........#
> ##########
> ```

Sample output:

> ```
> 14
> ```

Answer (score 4):

1. Please don't use `using namespace std` (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).
2. The variable names are really not helping. Why not call a maze a `maze` instead of `g`? What are `mj`, `z`, `l`, `k`? It's hard to follow the logic with names like these.
3. Instead of working with strings like `"K"`, `"."` and `"P"` it would be more efficient to use `char`s, and to give them meaningful names.
4. Instead of `int visited[30][30]`, `bool visited[30][30]` would be more natural

Here's an alternative version of your code, with some variables renamed, constants used, using char instead of string, not `using namespace std`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::pair;
using std::make_pair;
using std::vector;

const char start = 'P';
const char target = 'K';
const char empty = '.';

int dfs(char maze[30][30], pair<int, int> p)
{
    vector <pair<pair<int, int>, int> > v;
    bool visited[30][30] = {0};
    int x, y, k = 0;
    pair <pair<int, int>, int> mj;
    pair <pair<int, int>, int> z;
    pair <int, int> l;
    z = make_pair(make_pair(p.first, p.second), 0);
    v.push_back(z);
    while(v.size() != 0)
    {
        mj = v.front();
        l = mj.first;
        x = l.first;
        y = l.second;
        k = mj.second;
        v.erase(v.begin());
        if (maze[x][y] == target) {
            return k;
        }
        if((maze[x+1][y] == empty or maze[x+1][y] == target) and not(visited[x+1][y]))
        {
            v.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(x+1, y), k+1));
            visited[x+1][y] = true;
        }
        if((maze[x][y+1] == empty or maze[x][y+1] == target) and not(visited[x][y+1]))
        {
            v.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(x, y+1), k+1));
            visited[x][y+1] = true;
        }
        if((maze[x-1][y] == empty or maze[x-1][y] == target) and not(visited[x-1][y]))
        {
            v.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(x-1, y), k+1));
            visited[x-1][y] = true;
        }
        if((maze[x][y-1] == empty or maze[x][y-1] == target) and not(visited[x][y-1]))
        {
            v.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(x, y-1), k+1));
            visited[x][y-1] = true;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    pair <int, int> p;
    char s, maze[30][30];
    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cin >> s;
            maze[i][j] = s;
            if(maze[i][j] == start)
                p = make_pair(i, j);
        }
    }
    cout << dfs(maze, p) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Next, notice the duplication in this code:

> ```
> if((maze[x+1][y] == empty or maze[x+1][y] == target) and not(visited[x+1][y]))
> {
>     v.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(x+1, y), k+1));
>     visited[x+1][y] = true;
> }
> if((maze[x][y+1] == empty or maze[x][y+1] == target) and not(visited[x][y+1]))
> {
>     v.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(x, y+1), k+1));
>     visited[x][y+1] = true;
> }
> ```

The treatment for `(x+1, y)` is the same as for `(x, y+1)`, and `(x-1, y)` and `(x, y-1)`. Extract the duplicated parts to a helper method:

```
void check_maze_pos(char maze[30][30], int x, int y, int k, vector<pair<pair<int, int>, int> > &v, bool visited[30][30])
{
    if ((maze[x][y] == empty or maze[x][y] == target) and !visited[x][y])
    {
        v.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(x, y), k + 1));
        visited[x][y] = true;
    }
}
```

And then you can replace the 4 duplicated cases with these 4 simpler lines:

```
check_maze_pos(maze, x+1, y, k, v, visited);
check_maze_pos(maze, x, y+1, k, v, visited);
check_maze_pos(maze, x-1, y, k, v, visited);
check_maze_pos(maze, x, y-1, k, v, visited);
```

You can still improve further:

- Eliminate the duplication of the magic number 30 in many places
- Simplify the duplicated type definitions using `typedef`

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that, it's because those are the first letters of some words in my native language. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Single-letter words are poor names in general except a few special cases like `i`, `j`, `k`, for loop variables.

Answer (score 4):

A few other suggestions:

You are using the `and`, `or`, `not` aliases to the logical operators `&&`, `||`, `!`. In the C language, those are not reserved words, but macros defined in the header [`<iso646.h>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ciso646/). In C++, those are supposed to be globally visible without the need for the include file.

They might seem like a good idea at first, if you're not a big fan of punctuation, but I'll give you a couple reasons why you shouldn't use them:

- People in general are not familiar with those aliases. I bet you a good number of C++ programmers don't even know they exits.
- I've never actually seen them in use in any production code, so that might give you a hint about the overall view of the practice.
- The reason these aliases where introduced, I think, was for programmers that didn't have a keyboard with the punctuation chars. But I don't think such keyboards are still being manufactured today, so that renders them obsolete for that purpose.

---

You should use some typedefs for the `pairs`. This `pair<pair<int, int>, int>` is not just very cumbersome and error prone to type, but also conveys little information. What is a pair of `pair<in,int>` and `int`? What's that thing supposed to be called?

Also typedef the `vector<pair<pair<int, int>, int> >` to some name that tells the reader the purpose of the vector.

---

```
while(v.size() != 0)
```

Would probably be more idiomatic if using `empty()` instead:

```
while(!v.empty())
```

---

`std::pair` and friends are declared in the `<utility>` header. So it might be a good idea to explicitly include it to make dependencies clear. At the moment, you are depending on a "residual" include probably from `<vector>`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm not really familiar with the typedef but I'll google it.

Comment: @TomislavToplak - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef